# how to rendering the root page in nested routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

This is my dir structure on Next.js app:

```
pages
   |-users
   |     |-index.js
   |     |-[userid]
   |       |-index.js 
   index.js
```

when I call `domain.com/users/1`
I want the users->index.js component to be rendered as well. it only renders the /userid route with this structure.

equivalent in react-router `<Outlet/>`
but I couldn't find how to do in Next.js

Comment: Perhaps you can import the component from **users/index.js** into the component in **users/[userid]/index.js** and render it there?

Comment: @tromgy yes I know. but why would I use it that way everywhere when there is a way to automate it?

Comment: Next.js doesn't support nested layouts like react-router, but you can use a combination of [Custom App](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) and [route](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) awareness to conditionally render the contents of users/index in users/[userid]/index.

Comment: You may want to look into [optional catch-all dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes). It provides a way to handle both `/users` & `/users/1` paths on the same page.